# Generating a 3DLUT (.3dl file) for sRGB to CIELAB colorspace transformation

Tags: c++, image-processing

We already have a highly optimized class in our API to read 3D Lut(Nuke format) files and apply the transform to the image. So instead of iterating pixel-by-pixel and converting RGB values to Lab (RGB->XYZ->Lab) values using the complex formulae, I think it would be better if I generated a lookup table for RGB to LAB (or XYZ to LAB) transform. Is this possible?

I understood how the 3D Lut works for transformations from RGB to RGB, but I am confused about RGB to Lab as L, a and b have  different ranges. Any hints ?

**EDIT:**

Can you please explain me how the Lut will work ? 
Heres one explanation: [link](http://www.lightillusion.com/luts.html)

e.g Below is my understanding for a 3D Lut for RGB->RGB transform:
a sample Nuke 3dl Lut file:

```
0    64   128   192   256   320   384   448   512   576   640   704   768   832   896   960  1023 
R, G, B 
0, 0, 0 
0, 0, 64 
0, 0, 128 
0, 0, 192 
0, 0, 256 
.
.
.
0, 64, 0
0, 64, 64
0, 64, 128
.
.
```

Here instead of generating a 1024*1024*1024 table for the source 10-bit RGB values, each R,G and B range is quantized to 17 values generating a 4913 row table.
  The first line gives the possible quantized values (I think here only the length and the max value matter ).   Now suppose, if the source RGB value is (20, 20, 190 ), the output would be line # 4 (0, 0, 192) (using some interpolation techniques). Is that correct?
This one is for 10-bit source, you could generate a smiliar one for 8-bit by changing the range from 0 to 255?

Similarly, how would you proceed for sRGB->Lab conversion ?

Comment: It is possible for discrete values in the *source colorspace* (e.g. 8 bits per channel is suitable, >= 16 bits per channel results in an incredibly large table). The *target colorspace* can be as acurate as you want (it only determines *how much* you write in the table cells, not *how large* the table will be)

Comment: Alternative: GPGPU (possible with CUDA, OpenCL or GLSL)

Comment: You don't have to quantize the *output*. You can even store three floats for your Lab; it will only make the table linearly larger. However, if you compare 8 bits RGB to 16 bits RGB, your table has 16 million vs. 2.8e14 entries (I don't even know the name of this number...) So if you keep your *input signal* quantized with a low number of bits (i.e. 24 bits in RGB 8 bit per channel), generating and working with a table is suitable (see my answer).

Comment: ya, i don't know why i was confused before (I couldn't find good articles about 3dlut file formats). Maybe instead of using all 256 values for source RGB values I will use 17x17x17 instead.

Comment: May I ask why you unaccepted my answer? Is something wrong?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. Please see the edit.

Comment: They seem to use interpolation for that. That means, you precompute conversion values for a more coarse quantization, here 17 instead of 1024 values. Then, when looking up, you divide the RGB "coordinate" by the factor between these two quantizations. Instead of rounding to the nearest neighbour, you lookup all 4 nearest points and interpolate their values in the table. See also [bilinear filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering).

Comment: However, this will not result in *exact* values, as it is an approximation! For exact results, use the full LUT as in one of my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source colorspace is a triplet of bytes (RGB, 8 bits each) and both color spaces are stored in structs with the names `SourceColor` and `TargetColor` respectively, and you have a conversion function given like this:

```
TargetColor convert(SourceColor color) {
    return ...
}
```

Then you can create a table like this:

```
TargetColor table[256][256][256]; // 16M * sizeof(TargetColor) => put on heap!

for (int r, r < 256; ++r)
  for (int g, g < 256; ++g)
    for (int b, b < 256; ++b)
      table[r][g][b] = convert({r, g, b}); // (construct SourceColor from r,g,b)
```

Then, for the actual image conversion, use an alternative convert function (I'd suggest that you write a image conversion class which takes a function pointer / `std::function` in its constructor, so it's easily exchangeable):

```
TargetColor convertUsingTable(SourceColor source) {
    return table[source.r][source.g][source.b];
}
```

Note that the space consumption is `16M * sizeof(TargetColor)` (assuming 32 bit for `Lab` this will be `64MBytes`), so the table should be heap-allocated (it can be stored in-class if your class is going to live on the heap, but better allocate it with `new[]` in the constructor and store it in a smart pointer).

Comment: so, how would this work for L*a*b*, as TargetColor components have different ranges.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that... How do you store Lab values? Just replace this type in my code and you're done... Let's say your Lab type is called `Lab` and your RGB type is called `RGB`, then the table variable is `Lab table[256][256][256]` and the function `Lab convert(RGB color)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach makes use of graphics hardware, aka "general purpose GPU computing". There are some different tools for this, e.g. OpenGL GLSL, OpenCL, CUDA, ... You should gain an incredible speedup of about 100x and more compared to a CPU solution.

The most "compatible" solution is to use OpenGL with a special fragment shader with which you can perform computations. This means: upload your input image as a texture to the GPU, render it in a (target) framebuffer with a special shader program which converts your RGB data to Lab (or it can also make use of a lookup table, but most float computations on the GPU are faster than table / texture lookups, so we won't do this here).

First, port your RGB to Lab conversion function to GLSL. It should work on float numbers, so if you used integral values in your original conversion, get rid of them. OpenGL uses "clamp" values, i.e. float values between `0.0` and `1.0`. It will look like this:

```
vec3 rgbToLab(vec3 rgb) {
    vec3 lab = ...;
    return lab;
}
```

Then, write the rest of the shader, which will fetch a pixel of the (RGB) texture, calls the conversion function and writes the pixel in the color output variable (don't forget the alpha channel):

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 rgb = texture2D(texture, texCoord).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(lab, 1.0);
}
```

The corresponding vertex shader should write `texCoord` values of `(0,0)` in the bottom left and `(1,1)` in the top right of a target quad filling the whole screen (framebuffer).

Finally, use this shader program in your application by rendering on a framebuffer with the same size than your image. Render a quad which fills the whole region (without setting any transformations, just render a quad from the 2D vertices `(-1,-1)` to `(1,1)`). Set the uniform value `texture` to your RGB image which you uploaded as a texture. Then, read back the framebuffer from the device, which should hopefully contain your image in Lab color space.

Comment: I think I will stick to good ol' CPU for now :) I have written a image transform class which uses 3x3 matrices for colorspace transforms. I have used OpenMP which makes it fast enough for my needs. However, you cannot approximate the RGB -> L*a*b* using a Matrix. Hence the lookup table. But this sounds awesome.